# ListActivity getView - progress bar or perform in background?

Tags: android, background, progress-bar, listactivity

The getView operation of my ListActivity takes a long time to execute, because each row of my list takes a long time.

How can I add a progress bar to start before the list begins to populate and end when it is finished populating?

Alternatively, is it possible to have the getView operations performed asynchronously in the background somehow, so that my ListActivity take ages to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of the design should be that the getView should not take too much time. If the getView takes too much time, then it means you are blocking the UI.

I would suggest to use a worker thread to fetch the data for the list and populate the adapter. GetView should quickly generate the view and return.

You could use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to show the progress as the list data is fetched.